# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzaqp

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have installed react native stripe, and i got this error. But it never happen when i install another package. and then this is my build.gradle file.

> android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
    compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
      exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
      exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the same version** of Firebase and Google Play Services libraries.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
```

Or the latest (it requires also support v.26 and compileSdk = 26)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
```

Comment: that solved sir now i have another error
**Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**

Comment: It would be helpful a detail error. In any case this is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. You may wish to consider asking a separate question